# How to insert a SVG img inline in header.php of Wordpress, the purpose is modify the CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, svg

I am trying to modify the css of a SVG image(the logo) in a header.php of a Wordpress custom theme.

Here is the code in header.php:

```
 <!-- logo -->
    <a class="logo" href="<?php echo home_url(); /* insert home link */ ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); /* add theme path */ ?>/img/logo.svg" alt="<?php bloginfo('title'); /* insert blog title */ ?> ">
    </a>
```

To modify the CSS of the SVG I have to inline it, but I don't know how to do, this SVG is saved from Illustrator.

I tried to add this jQuery script that transforms a SVG image in an inline SVG, but I don't the see the image in the browser, I see it if I inspect the element.

```
/**
 * Replace all SVG images with inline SVG
 */
    jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
        var $img = jQuery(this);
        var imgID = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

        jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
            }

            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);

        }, 'xml');

    });
```

Thanks for all the support.
Carlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to style svg with attributes like `fill`, `stroke` or `stroke-width` for example. This is very usefull if you create you image actualy by code, for example:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

You have an svg image file and use it as `src` in your `<img>` tag.

It is not the direct answer to your question, but maybe it solves your problem, if you save the other version of your image also as an svg file (should be less than 10kb, so no performance problems) and change the `src` value.

In the comment I read you want to achieve a dark / light mode and also your logo image should change if another mode is selected, like:

```
  document.getElementById("my_image_id").src = "my_image_file.svg";
```

---

Another solution would be to do all the look changes via the css and just set the data-theme with javascript. CSS will make the rest for you.

You could show your logo as a background-image, using the a parent:

```
<a class="logo" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <!-- here comes the logo -->
</a>
```

and in your CSS:

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px; /*your dimensions*/
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(my_image_file.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

---

**How to create dark / light mode without jQuery and minimum Javascript**

This is more than you asked for, but maybe can help your task make more easy. You can give your html element an attribute, for example called `data-theme` and your button only changes this attribute value with javascript.

So in the html: You change the data-theme value with your toggle button (with a nice transition).

```
<html lang="en" data-theme="light">
    <body>
    .
    .
    .
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="theme" /><label for="switch">Toggle</label>
    .
    .
    .
    <script>

    var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name=theme]');

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            trans()
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        } else {
            trans()
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        }
    })

    let trans = () => {
        document.documentElement.classList.add('transition');
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('transition');
        }, 1000)
    }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's all for the javascript and html part of the job. The rest is CSS with normal variables, you set once and use in your code.

```
html {
    --bg: #AEAEAE;
    --color-headings: #666;
    --logo-source: url(my_light_logo.svg);
}

html[data-theme='dark'] {
    --bg: #333333;
    --color-headings: #FFF;
    --logo-source: url(my_dark_logo.svg);
}

body {
    background-color: var(--bg);
}

h1 {
    color: var(--color-headings);
}

.logo {
    background: var(--logo-source);
}

html.transition,
html.transition *,
html.transition *:before,
html.transition *:after {
    transition: all 750ms !important;
    transition-delay: 0 !important;
}
```

This way you change everything about the styling in your css, and only trigger the data-theme change with javascript on your button. For me, this seems to be the more logic way to achive light / dark mode, as CSS is there just for styling.

Hope it helps and maybe is something of interest for you!

Comment: Hi @rank, my purpose is to modify the logo's stroke, not the dimensions, I'm making a script with Jquery, clicking a button I change the colors of the webPage, for people who need different contrast.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the comment. I changed my answer and showed you an alternative way using background-image. Moreover I added a way to create light / dark mode without jquery, hope it helps you out! Happy to help.

Comment: Hi @rank, I solved the issue with your support, with background-image logo. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Glad to here! Please accept my answer as it solved your issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

```css
.main-header {
  background: url(logo.svg) no-repeat top left;
  background-size: contain;
}

.no-svg .main-header {
  background-image: url(logo.png);
}

something like this.. with the help of CSS.
```

Comment: Your answer does not explain anything about the code you show. Moreover, there is nothing in the question about a main-header class or how to set as background image. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer